# TikZ arrowheads on every dash of dashed line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'd like to create a dashed line in TikZ with an arrow head at the end of each dash.  The following code accomplishes this using a \foreach loop but looking for a way to do this with a style key instead.  Something similar to

```
\draw [densely dashed, ->] (0,0) -- ++(100pt,0);
```

but places arrowheads on all dashes not just the end.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [densely dashed] (0,0) -- ++(100pt,0);
    \foreach \i in {0,5,10,...,100}{%
        \draw [->] (\i*1pt,-0.25) -- ++(3pt,0);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess for this one of the simplest possibilities will be to employ `decorations.markings`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt,postaction={decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 3pt and 1 step 5pt with {\arrow{>};}}}] (0,0) -- ++(100pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the real application, one could make this a style, or, what might be better for curved paths, just declare a new (meta) decoration. Luckily, the pgfmanual has on p. 1007 a meta decoration that one only has to slightly modify to arrive at

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{many arrows}{initial}{ 
\state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=arrow] {
    \pgfmathdivide{100}{\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}
    \let\factor\pgfmathresult
    %\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}
    \pgfset{/pgf/decoration/segment length=4pt}
  }
  \state{arrow}[
switch if less than=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength to final, width=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength/3,
next state=end arrow]
  {
    \decoration{curveto}
    \beforedecoration
    {
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointmetadecoratedpathfirst}
} }
\state{end arrow}[width=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength/3, next state=move] {
    \decoration{curveto}
    \beforedecoration{\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointmetadecoratedpathfirst}}
    \afterdecoration
    {
      \pgfsetarrowsend{Latex[length=1pt,width=1pt]}
      \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\state{move}[width=\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength/2, next state=arrow]{} \state{final}{}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thin,decorate,decoration={many arrows,meta-segment length=3pt}] (0,0) .. controls (0,2) and (3,2) .. (3,0)
        .. controls (3,-2)  and (0,-2)  .. (0,-4)
        .. controls (0,-6)  and (3,-6)  .. (3,-8)
        .. controls (3,-10) and (0,-10) .. (0,-8);
\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

Here I zoom into the outcome to show that the arrows are tiny. (Recall that the diameter is 3cm.)

[image]